# fix cannot find symbol in public class java

Tags: java

```
public class Book {

    //variables
    private String title = "";
    int isbn = 0;
    int quantity = 0;

    public Book(String title, int isbn, int quantity) throws Exception {
        this.setTitle(title);
        this.setIsbn(isbn);
        this.setQuantity(quantity);
    }

    //toString method that return with book information
    public String toString() {
        String s = "";

        s = "title:" + this.title;
        s = s + "\nIsbn:" + this.isbn;
        s = s + "\nQuantity:" + this.quantity;

        return s;
    }

    public void setTitle(String newTitle) throws Exception {
        if ((newTitle != null)) {
            this.title = newTitle;
        } else {
            BookException be = new BookException();
            be.setMessage("wrong input, title should not be blank.");
            throw be;
        }
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return this.title;
    }
}
```

why there was no symbol in the code `this.setIsbn(isbn)` and `this.setQuantity(quantity)`

Comment: Where you have methods `setIsbn` and `setQuantity`?

Answer (score 0):

Because your class do not have methods setIsbn and setQuantity you have to create them and then only you can use them

```
public void setIsbn(int isbn) {
   this.isbn = isbn;
}

public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
   this.quantity = quantity;
}
```

And on similar lines you should also have getters for these

```
public int getIsbn() {
   return this.isbn;
}

public int getQuantity() {
   return this.quantity;
}
```